# Последний элемент массива в цикле foreach

Tags: php

Подскажите, как у последнего элемента массива убрать запятую?

```
// Вывод
$out = '<script type="application/json" class="w-json">{ "items": [';

// Выводим каждую картинку из галереи
foreach( $pictures as $pic ){
    $src = $pic->guid;
    $medium_array = image_downsize($pic->ID, 'medium');

    $out .= '{"width": '. $medium_array[1] .', "height": '. $medium_array[2] .', "url": "'. $src .'"},';
}

$out .= '] }</script>';
```

Comment: напишите в цикле $inner[] = ... а после цикла вставьте через implode()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте ф-ю [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php) для формирования JSON.

Соберите в цикле массив из ассоц. массивов с данными по каждой фотографии. Затем его оберните в ассоц. массив с единственным ключём "items", и получите грамотную JSON-строку на выходе ф-ии json_encode(). Останется только эту строку вставить в нужном месте тега `<script>`:

```
$items = array();

// Выводим каждую картинку из галереи
foreach( $pictures as $pic ){
    $medium_array = image_downsize($pic->ID, 'medium');
    array_push( $items, array(
        "width"  => $medium_array[1],
        "height" => $medium_array[2],
        "url"    => $pic->guid,
    ));
}

// Вывод тега script
$out = sprintf(
    '<script type="application/json" class="w-json">%s</script>',
    json_encode( array( "items" => $items))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Если известно, сколько символов остается после последней запятой (а я так понимаю, что известно, так как Вы же их и добавляете в конце), то вопрос решается очень просто, например:

```
$out = '{"url": "ideone.com" },';
$out[strlen($out)-1] = ' ';
echo $out;
```

Сама запятая меняется на пробел и строка становится валидной (Вам ведь это нужно).

Answer (score 0):

Получить доступ к последнему элементу массива

```
$pic[count($pic)-1]
```

Удалить запятую последнего элемента

```
str_replace(",","",$pic[count($pic)-1]);
```

Также можно добавить условие в foreach, которое сравнивает индекс текущего значения с индексом последнего элемента массива, но насколько оправдан такой костыль сказать сложно, лучше использовать первый вариант

```
if( key($pictures)==(count($pic)-1) ){//
    str_replace(",","",$pictures);
}
```